# SQLalchemy many-to-one-to-many OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have several classes  which inherit from from `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base`:

```
class Worker(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workers"
    worker_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    jobs: Mapped[list[Job]] = relationship()

class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "jobs"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    worker_name: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("workers.worker_name"))
    tools: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("tools.tool"))

class Tool(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tools"

    tool: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    jobs: Mapped[list[Job]] = relationship()
```

I get data from various sources.

There can be a worker with multiple jobs, and a tool used for multiple jobs, by multiple users. I add the jobs and users first, and plan to add the tools from another data source afterwards. But when try to add the jobs I get an OperationalError:

```
 (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: jobs.tools
```

What is the correct approach for this kind of one-many-many relationship? ie:

```
job_id   worker_id
job1     worker1
job2     worker1 
job3     worker2
job4     worker2
job5     worker3

tool_id  job_id
tool1    job1
tool2    job1
tool3    job2
tool3    job5
tool4    job4
tool5    job3
tool5    job3
```

etc

Comment: Make `Job.tools` nullable?